# Resizing Docker disk image to a non-standard size

Tags: macos, docker

I'm installing Docker on Mac OSX and need to move the image to a 16GB SD card. However the smallest disk size is 16GB in the UI, which won't fit on a 16GB SD card. Is there a way to resize to to 15GB?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to do? Where does an SD card come in the picture from while using OSX? Where do you want to transfer your image from and to? Which UI are you talking about?

Comment: I'm trying to make the image smaller then 16GB, so it fits an SD card (and therefore doesn't take up space on my hard drive). So I'd like to transfer the image from its current place, which is /Users/zolcsi/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/Docker.raw to the SD card. But the UI doesn't allow me to set an image smaller then 16GB. See this picture of the UI: https://imgur.com/a/FvjzKVT

Comment: If you'd look at the screenshot, it says that the size of the image on the disk is only 4.1 GB. So, you should be able to transfer the file on a 16 GB SD card. Docker.raw file does not take a lot of space on the disk, It's a misconception because the `ls` utility provided the logical size of the file rather than the physical file. Read here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/faqs. I'll create an answer if this information helps.

Comment: unfortunately OSX won't allow me to do that. https://imgur.com/a/mmAgPK1 I tried to copy it via the command line using rsync, but it's same result, it sees it as a 16GB file that just doesn't fit the 16GB SD card.

Comment: Does it allow you to import the image from a location of your choice? I've never used Docker for Mac.

Comment: Not on the UI. I can only move the existing image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to do it. To reduce the size on the command line, you can simply edit the following file:
~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json
Find the "diskSizeMiB" field there and edit it as you wish.